# "No such field" when attempting to open a contact in CiviCRM Spark

Tags: contacts, civicrm-spark

When I attempt to open a contact in CiviCRM Spark, I get the error message below, any ideas?  See also screenshot.

[image]Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
DB Error: no such field
Return to home page.

Answer (score 3):

CiviCRM has an undocumented limit on the number of custom fields inside a custom group, which might be 65 fields, or it might depend on the type of fields (text vs numeric).

Looking at your database, 71 custom fields had been created, but only the first 65 had actually been created in the underlying storage, which is what was causing the error.

To mitigate the issue, I disable those fields that do not really exist, and I recommend that you delete them completely.

You can then create a separate custom group for more fields. Ideally, you can try to group them logically somehow (by thematic?) so that it looks more intuitive. The end result will be exactly the same as if they were in a single group, but visually there will be some separator between the two groups.

(I'm a CiviCRM Spark admin, so I could view the detailed error log and examine the underlying database. You can also email us at spark-at-civicrm.org)